# How to prove triangle inequality for $\|u\| = \langle{u,u}\rangle ^{0.5}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

I want to prove that $\|u\| = \langle{u,u}\rangle ^{0.5}$ satisfies the 4 conditions for being a norm. I've already proved the first 3 conditions but I'm stuck on the triangle inequality i.e. $$\|x + y\| \leq \|x\| + \|y\|$$
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Try squaring both sides.

Comment: @Slade I've tried that before. But I'm stuck on something else which I can't prove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $ \|u+v\|^2=\|u\|^2+\langle u,v\rangle+\langle v,u\rangle+\|v\|^2.$

**Edit:** We have: 
\begin{align}
 \|u+v\|^2&=\|u\|^2+\langle u,v\rangle+\langle v,u\rangle+\|v\|^2 \\
&= \|u\|^2+\langle u,v\rangle+\overline{\langle u,v\rangle}+\|v\|^2 \\
&=\|u\|^2+2\Re\langle u,v\rangle+\|v\|^2 \\
&\le \|u\|^2+2\left|\langle u,v\rangle\right|+\|v\|^2 \\ \tag1
&\le \|u\|^2+2\|u\|\|v\|+\|v\|^2 \\
&= (\|u\|+\|v\|)^2,
\end{align}

where we have used the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in $(1)$. Taking square roots, since both sides are positive, we yield the desired result: $$\|u+v\|\le\|u\|+\|v\|.$$

Comment: I've already reached this far but I don't know how to proceed. That is How to show that your statement is less than norm of u + norm of v?

Comment: also we can't use ||u^2|| instead of <u,u>^0.5 since we have not proven it to be a norm yet

Comment: We have: $\|u\|=\langle u,u \rangle^{0.5} \implies \|u\|^2=\langle u,u \rangle.$

Comment: We want to prove that a vector inner-product namely $<u,u>^{0.5}$ is a norm. We can't use something we want to prove in the process

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator We don't need to prove that we can write $\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle} = \| x\|$, that's part of the definition.  What we need to prove is that $\| \cdot \|$ satisfies the triangle inequality, which JVV just did.  There is nothing circular here, but if you prefer, it can be easily rewritten without the symbol $\| \cdot \|$, to show that $\sqrt{\langle u+v,u+v \rangle} \leq \sqrt{\langle u,u\rangle} + \sqrt{\langle v,v\rangle}$, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: @Slade Exactly. How to prove your representation?

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator JVV just proved it!  I don't understand why you have a problem with $\| \cdot \|$, but if you just rewrite $\| a\|$ as $\sqrt{\langle a,a\rangle}$, the proof above is more than sufficient.

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator: At no stage in this proof am I relying on the properties of a norm, I am only using the notation you provided (which is the standard notation). You have defined some object (which turns out to be the standard norm) as $\|u\|=\langle u,u \rangle^{0.5}.$ This is the only 'property' I have used. The rest relies on properties of complex numbers and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.